# Export picture marker symbol in legend in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, export, legend, markers

I used a picture marker symbol (from JPG file) in order to represent a point layer with unique values symbology.

[image]

this is the symbol in the map:

[image]

My problem is when i export the map to a JPG file, the picture marker symbol became Blurry.

This is the resolution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The resolution doesn't matter. It's a bug I experience a lot with picture symbols when exporting to PDFs. Sometimes it works fine and other times the exact same symbol comes out like it did for you. I've tried absolutely everything I can think of to prevent it from happening. What I would suggest in this instance is just making it a character symbol. The symbol you showed above can be made using character markers which will prevent the glitching of the fidelity when exporting.

Comment: @Adam_Kara you should turn your comment into an answer as it is a good reply worth voting up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the JPG file into EMF file using Inkscape, then imported the symbol  into the ArcMap. That's how it looks after the exportation:

[image]